# How to increase timeout in travis-ci for my selenium tests written on java?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, webdriver, travis-ci

I have a tests wrintten on java (which passes on local machine, test runs about 30 min) and I need to increase timeout in travis-ci, can I change timeout by changing .tavis.yml? 
This is my .tavis.yml file:

```
language: java

cache: apt

before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install -qq default-jdk maven

env:
  - JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64

script:
  - travis_wait mvn package -Dtestng=test.xml
```

I'm asking because I have an error on travis:

```
Timeout (20 minutes) reached. Terminating "mvn package -Dtestng=test.xml"
```

So, do I have any option to change time out? May be I need to write down something to .tavis.yml? Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can increase the timeout by modifying your script command. For instance, to increase the timeout to half an hour:

```
  - travis_wait 30 mvn package -Dtestng=test.xml
```

See Mor's answer for a great alternative that doesn't "hang" the build output for 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your tests are not producing any output, which usually results in a timeout in 10 minutes.

However since you're prefixing the build command with `travis_wait`, that timeout is increased to 20 minutes.

> The shell environment in our build system provides a function that helps to work around that, at least for longer than 10 minutes.
>
> travis_wait writes a short line to the build log every minutes for 20 minutes, extending the amount of time your command has to finish.

Double check to see if you tests are hanging.

Comment: What do you mean output? You mean System.out.println()?

Comment: Anything that maven or your code prints to standard output.

Comment: Apparently `travis_wait` buffers all of the output until the command has finished executing, which is less than ideal because it means that if your build takes a long time, it will take just as long to see errors emerge.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the following solution [taken from a GitHub Issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4190#issuecomment-169987525) that works for me:

```
script:
  - .travis/test.sh
```

Where `test.sh` looks like this:

```
# send the long living command to background
./long-running-operation.sh &

# Constants
RED='\033[0;31m'
minutes=0
limit=3

while kill -0 $! >/dev/null 2>&1; do
  echo -n -e " \b" # never leave evidences!

  if [ $minutes == $limit ]; then
    echo -e "\n"
    echo -e "${RED}Test has reached a ${minutes} minutes timeout limit"
    exit 1
  fi

  minutes=$((minutes+1))

  sleep 60
done

exit 0
```